# UIPanGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer at the same time

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, uitapgesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

Here is my little situation. I'm moving a ccsprite with uipanGesture. I can move it all around not problem, and I have a spot on screen which I can shoot using uitapgesture.

```
-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
location = [self convertToNodeSpace:location];

if (location.x > winSize.width * .6 && location.y <winSize.height/2) {
  NSLog(@"fire");  
}
```

I added the delegate method so when I'm panning, I can click the fire button: everything works fine.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
  return YES;
}
```

But when I'm not panning and just firing using the uitapgesture, I can not pan when I am firing... The reason I think it is happening is because it's registering the last tap as 
`recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` since I'm not panning.

Anybody knows a way I can tap and not register the tap as the `if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`

I tried if `(location.x < winSize.width/2)` but it did not work.

Comment: Can we see where you create the gestures?

Comment: I create them in either 2 places on this example I created it in the init but I have created them in the app delegate before.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set up a gesture recogniser chain using requireGestureRecognizerToFail. This will mean that a gesture being executed will be forced to fail, giving precedence to the second gesture.

So I think you want to have your [ requireGestureToFail: ].

Comment: I did a tutorial a while back http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=256 and in this tutorial I have the provision for both pinch and rotate gestures to coincide with one another in the way you wish your pan and tap to work, have a look see if it helps. In the mean time I will try and create a small project that exhibits the behaviour you want and see if there is something inherent in using a tap and a pan together that is causing strangeness.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to check it out now

Comment: so i played around with the tutorial its pretty good but for some reason its not working for me. when i'm panning the tap works fine i can tap all day long its once i start tapping i can not pan...i tried switching maxNumberOfTouches to 2 which help but my ccsprite jumps around the screen so i cant use that...still looking for help on this matter

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if anybody is interested in this post but i did fix the problem like 90%
using the following

```
  for(int i=0; i<[recognizer numberOfTouches]; i++){
    CGPoint pt = [recognizer locationOfTouch:i inView:recognizer.view];
    pt = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:pt];
    pt = [self convertToNodeSpace:pt];

   if (i==0) {
   //stuff
     }
```